# How to get a completly self contained Non-Chromium browser on Linux?

Tags: linux, firefox, browser, chromium, portable

With the Firefox solutions I've tried, I can't just copy paste a folder and all the settings, addons etc will be defined inside, not on some profile folder in the system.

I've used a way to make Google Chrome Portable, and works very nice, it's just I'm trying to avoid Chromium builds.

Either with Firefox or another non-Chromium browser has anyone came up with a way to be able to move folders with browsers around and have them just work?

thanks

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/73123/portable-firefox-linux It is quite old but should still work.

Comment: See [this article](https://www.airaghi.net/en/2017/03/22/install-mozilla-firefox-portable-on-linux/) for a script that will take a complete Firefox installation and create the portable installation.

Comment: Recently I downloaded Firefox from the Firefox downloads page, (currently it's firefox-91.0.2.tar.bz2), and expanded it. It put Firefox and its support files in a separate folder. As far as I could tell it's profile folder was also contained, though you could link to an outside profile folder if you want to. I didn't check it too deeply as I only needed temporary use of an older version.

Answer (score -1):

You can download [Firefox Portable](https://portableapps.com/apps/internet/firefox_portable) and [Google Chrome Portable](https://portableapps.com/apps/internet/google_chrome_portable) from [PortableApps.com](https://portableapps.com)

Comment: Thank you. Those are for Windows. I was asking Linux.